# Can I apply for a Canadian student permit while in Canada?

Tags: canada, study, permits, student-visas

I was admitted to the 2023 summer session at ENAP Quebec, and I received my CAQ, my return being in 2023, I am waiting for the beginning of 2023 to apply for a study permit.

However, I also hold a temporary visitor visa valid for 5 years, and I plan to go to Canada next December.  I would like to know if I could take advantage of the fact that I am on Canadian territory to do my application for a study permit directly, and take advantage of the fact that the visitor visa allows you to stay a maximum of 6 months in the territory to make my application for PE, find my accommodation, and continue directly with the study permit.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

---

Bonjour à toutes et à tous,

J'ai été admis à la session d'été 2023 à l'ENAP Québec, et j'ai reçu mon CAQ, ma rentrée étant en 2023, j'attends le début 2023 pour faire ma demande de permis d'étude.

Cependant, je suis aussi titulaire d'un visa temporaire visiteur valable 05 ans , et j'ai prévu de me rendre au Canada, en décembre prochain, je conserverai savoir, si je pourrais profiter du fait que je sois sur le territoire canadien pour faire ma demande de permis d'études directement, et profiter du fait que le visa visiteur autorise à rester 06 mois maximum sur le territoire pour faire, ma demande de PE, rechercher mon logement, et enchainer directement avec le permis d'études.

Merci d'avance pour votre retour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but not (necessarily) recommended.

[Only certain classes of people may apply for a study permit inside Canada.](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/study-permit/apply.html) Usually, only people with existing or recently expired worker or student (or other long-term) status, or pending refugee or permanent residence applications, or families of these people qualify. Currently, Ukrainian nationals and their families also qualify due to the ongoing situation.

One other notable situation that allows you to apply inside Canada even if you enter with a visitor status is when you are a exchange or visiting student for less than six months, or are following a short-term course or study program required to be accepted at an eligible study-permit required institution.

If you do not qualify for inland processing, you are still eligible to apply online for a study permit as if you were in your country of origin outside Canada, even if you are physically in Canada.
If your application is approved, you will have to leave Canada and enter again to obtain the study permit (or 'flagpole'). The fact that you are in Canada does not make the processing any easier or faster since the application is processed by the office assigned to your country of origin. In fact, there may be complications if the office requires an in-person interview or additional documents that you may not be able to easily obtain while you are in Canada.

You are not allowed to study in Canada before you obtain your study permit if a study permit is required for your study plan.

Comment: thank for your reply. it's clear for me. I will apply for my country.